# Meaning of would in this context

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of would in the sentence below or why we use would (grammaritically) in this situation?

“Wouldn’t this also be the perfect course for prospective arsonists to sign up for?”

I have checked

https://www.google.com.my/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/would

But I get confused to understand which case is related to this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Wouldn’t" here mark the question as 'rhetorical'.

"Wouldn’t this also be the perfect course for prospective arsonists to sign up for?" is actually a statement in question form, not a question seeking for an answer,

- "Would this also be the perfect course for prospective arsonists to sign up for?" is a real question, asking "would this be?" or "would this not be?"
- "Wouldn’t this also be the perfect course for prospective arsonists to sign up for?" is a rhetorical question that the answer (statement) is always "(of course) this would be"

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I want to understand why we use would here from grammatical point of view. It is not request, not conditional and not repeated action in the past... is it possibility that unlikely happened?

Comment: 'would' imply 'have the potential of'

Comment: "would it be..." means "does it has the potential of being..."

Comment: Is the context related to the present or past grammatically?

Comment: It is in the present